# Android studio layouts

Tags: java, android-studio

Is it possible  to use Different layouts in One Android studio app.  For example um planning  to use linear layout in my splash screen,  Relative layout in my login and Sign up while my home activity i use constraint layout

Comment: ​Y​e​s​, ​i​t is​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use different layouts in one application. You can even use all kinds of layouts within one layout file:

`activity_login.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:width="wrap_content"
      android:height="wrap_content">

      .. Views / Nested layouts ..

   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

More information on layouts can be found [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout).